# Uninstall ubuntu from external hard drive + remove bootloader from internal hd

Tags: grub2, uninstall, bootloader

I have created a bootable usb stick with linuxlive and Ubuntu.I then tried to install ubuntu on my external harddrive. However I guess I wrongly picked the drive where the boot section is installed, it now is installed on my internal (C:) drive.

When I open the bios bootsequence it says Ubuntu 2 times? As if the boot is installed twice?

I'd like to uninstall Ubuntu from my external drive but most important: I don't want Grub to be start up on my PC.

I tried booting in Windows 8 recovery mode and used the following commands:
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot

However the ubuntu choices wont disappear?

I then tried to add bootrec /scanos and bootrec /rebuildbcd to the commands but somehow this wont work either.

Anyone got some ideas?

Thank you in advance!
Best regards,
Bart